# Same Model different views with different validation error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with follwing content

```
public class Content
{

public string Name{get;set;}
public string Age{get;set;}

}
```

Now I have two views.

```
View 1: Supplier

Textbox for Supplier Name:
TextBox for Supplier Age:

View2: Receiver
TextBox for Receiver Name:
Textbox for Receiver Age:
```

Both of the above partial views are on same main view within single form. When I submit the form I should be able to validate each section separately. e.g. Supplier Name cannot be blank. Receiver Age cannot be blank etc. Also when posted to Action Method each should be resolved to Content model type. Can it be possible? or should I create two models with same type of members?

Comment: this is possible. Should you? Not sure, I guess it depends on what you are trying to do exactly. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

While the objects have the same properties, the context is different. I would recommend creating two separate models.

**For instance:** It is very possible that you might want to add a property that only applies to Supplier, but not Receiver. You would not want the receiver to also get it and just have it ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

MVC Required Validation does not support multi error messages for a property
    yet. Therefore, if you want to re-use `Content` class and get different error messages for Name and Age, there hasn't been a way yet unless you make a custom client-side validation like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC.

In this approach, you can display whatever error message you like. However, if js is disabled, you're going to get the original error messages from the server.

Personally, I'd suggest creating 2 different models because you don't have to rewrite the rules for every property types (eg: datetime, email, range etc.)

```
public class SupplierModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Supplier Name cannot be blank")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Supplier Age cannot be blank")]
    public string Age {get; set;}
}

public class ReceiverModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Receiver Name cannot be blank")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Receiver Age cannot be blank")]
    public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

Whichever way you go, the controller action will collect the appropriate properties.